# Epson XP-342 - Enabling manual duplex

Tags: drivers, printing, epson, duplex-printing

I just installed an *Epson XP-342* on my Ubuntu 18.10 system.
I used Epson's drivers [from here, the Epson website](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule).

Everything works fine (printing, scanning) apart from manual duplex.
It is blocked in all printer dialogs and in printer setup.

Is it possible to somehow enable it?